# How can i add the column name in every sheet of several excel using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

> Can someone please help me to add a file name column in every sheet of several excel files . I am sharing my code here.
>
> please help me to add a code where i can add a column of file name in every sheet

```
import os
import pandas as pd

files = os.listdir("XXXX")

print("All files in the given directory are :", files)

files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

print("Excel files in this directory are :", files_xlsx)

y = "XXXX"

excels = [pd.ExcelFile(y +'/'+ name) for name in files_xlsx]

for each in excels:
    sheets =pd.ExcelFile(each).sheet_names


print ("Sheet names in these excel files are : ", sheets)

NSheets = len(sheets)

print ("Number of different Sheet names in these excel files are : ", NSheets)

for z in sheets:
    if z != 'Portfolios' and z != 'SP Search Term Report' and z != 'Sheet5':
        frames = list()
        for x in excels:
            try:
                x.sheet_names.index(z)
                frames.append(x.parse(x.sheet_names.index(z), header=None, index_col=None))
                frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]# keep only header from first file for each sheetname
                frames['filename'] = os.path.basename(x)
                combined = pd.concat(frames)
                combined.to_excel("XXXX/Output_" + z + ".xlsx", header=False, index=False)
            except:

                pass
```